# Как запустить скрытое окно?

Tags: c#, wpf

Дело в том, что для `IntPtr` мне нужно создать отдельное окно, в рамках MVVM я не могу использовать основное т.к. модель должна быть самостоятельной

Сейчас я создаю окно так:

```
new Window() {
    Visibility = Visibility.Hidden,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
    Width = 0,
    Height = 0
};
```

Но есть проблемы:

1) Несмотря на `Visibility.Hidden` окно сначала появляется на некоторое время, а уже потом исчезает, по этому я и пишу остальные свойства

2) Несмотря на отсутствие верхнего заголовка (`WindowStyle.None`) и нулевые размеры кона, все равно появляется его обводка, её видно

3) Новое окно так же на время появляется в панели задач

Как можно создать полностью скрытое окно из кода?

Comment: Непосредственно работать с win.api. Только такое решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С win.api загнул. Предлагаю следующие решение из костылей и велосипедов. Окно банально запускается в самом правом нижнем углу, со свойствами `Visibility.Hidden` и `ShowInTaskbar = false`. Данный костыль полностью делает незаметным открытие данного окна - не появляется обводка на пару секунд. А также `ShowInTaskbar = false` скрывает в менеджере задач данное окно.

```
   Window wnd = new Window()
    {
        Visibility = Visibility.Hidden,
        ShowInTaskbar = false,
        Title = "Hidden window",
        Width = 0,
        Height = 0,
        WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual,
        Left = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth,
        Top = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight
    };
    wnd.Show();
```